Proof of weights maximizing sharpe of a portfolio
Given a portfolio of $n$ assets with mean vector $\mu$ and correlation matrix $\Sigma$, the optimal weights $w$ on the $n$ assets to maximize overall sharpe is found by
$$\max_{w:||w||=1}{\dfrac{\mu^T w}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}}}$$
and the entries of $w$ are nonnegative. I have seen in this post (and various other places) that the weights solving this optimization problem are given as
$$w=\Sigma^{-1}\mu$$
However, I have not been able to find a reference as to why this is true.
Question: What is the proof that these are the optimal weights? Bonus: what if $\Sigma$ is not-invertible (strictly positive semidefinite)?

Hi, can you show what you've tried so far? Did you already try the condition for finding a (local) optimum, i.e. $f'(w^*)=0$?

If the optimization problem is:
$\max_{w} \frac{w'\boldsymbol{\mu}}{(w'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}w)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$
constrained to $w\textbf{1}=1$, then we just use Lagrange multipliers:
$$L = \frac{w'\boldsymbol{\mu}}{(w'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}w)^{\frac{1}{2}}} + \lambda(w\textbf{1} - 1)$$
Then taking the partials wrt $w$ and $\lambda$, we have:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w} = \boldsymbol{\mu} (w'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}w)^{-\frac{1}{2}} - (w'\boldsymbol{\mu}(w'\boldsymbol{\Sigma}w)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}w + \lambda\textbf{1}=0$$
$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = w'\textbf{1} - 1 = 0$$
Then the result follows.
For your 2nd question, A matrix is invertible if and only if it has a non-zero determinant. But from the definition of a correlation matrix, the only way for a correlation matrix to have a non-zero determinant is for the correlations to all equal $1$ or $-1$. Of which case, the optimal portfolio is trivially obvious. If there are less datapoints than dimensions, you can perform PCA analysis, or you can use singular value decomposition to compute the pseudoinverse of a matrix.

Looks a bit like the proof of inverse variance weighting https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting

Thats My Quant My Quantitative: You have a typo in the "For your 2nd question" part because it can currently be re-arranged to say that a correlation matrix is invertible if and only all of the correlations are equal to 1 or -1. That's not correct. Thanks.
